# How to Combine Multiple If Statements in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to combine multiple (more than 64) If statements into one cell. I'm not very fluent in Excel so I may even be doing this wrong.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

If `[(Cell 1 = X) AND (Cell 2 = Y) then Cell 3 = Z]`
or
If `[(Cell 1 = X) AND (Cell 2 = B) the Cell 3 = C]`

I have 100 possibilities for Cell 1, and 2 possibilities for Cell 2. The combination of Cell 1 and 2 will produce a specific answer in Cell 3.

I hope this make sense.

So far I've tried the following If statement which works, but is too long (longer than 64).

```
=IF(AND(B6="AF001.1",C6="US"),"5.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF010",C6="US"),"17.2",
IF(AND(B6="Z284.1",C6="US"),"8.5",
IF(AND(B6="Z284.2",C6="US"),"17.8",  
IF(AND(B6="AF016.1",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.2",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.3",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.4",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.5",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.6",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.7",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.8",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.9",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.10",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.11",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.12",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.13",C6="US"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST001",C6="US"),"6",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.2",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.3",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.4",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.5",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.6",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.7",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.8",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.9",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.10",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.11",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST002.12",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.1",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.2",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.3",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.4",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.5",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.6",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.7",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.8",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.9",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.10",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.11",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST003.12",C6="ALL"),"36.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST004.1",C6="US"),"11.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST004.2",C6="US"),"11.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST004.3",C6="US"),"11.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST004.4",C6="US"),"11.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST005",C6="ALL"),"21.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.1",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.2",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.3",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.4",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.5",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.6",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.7",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.8",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.9",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.10",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.11",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.12",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.13",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.14",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.15",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.16",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.17",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST006.18",C6="ALL"),"80",
IF(AND(B6="ST007",C6="ALL"),"19",
IF(AND(B6="ST008.1",C6="US"),"12.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST008.2",C6="US"),"12.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST008.3",C6="US"),"12.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST008.4",C6="US"),"12.5",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.1",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.2",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.3",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.4",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.5",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.6",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.7",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.8",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.9",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.10",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.11",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.12",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.13",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.14",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.15",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.16",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.17",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.18",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.19",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.20",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.21",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.22",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.23",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.24",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.25",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.26",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.27",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST009.28",C6="ALL"),"108",
IF(AND(B6="ST010",C6="US"),"5.3",
IF(AND(B6="ST010",C6="ALL"),"6.8",
IF(AND(B6="ST008.1",C6="ALL"),"14",
IF(AND(B6="ST008.2",C6="ALL"),"14",
IF(AND(B6="ST008.3",C6="ALL"),"14",
IF(AND(B6="ST008.4",C6="ALL"),"14",
IF(AND(B6="ST004.1",C6="ALL"),"13",
IF(AND(B6="ST004.2",C6="ALL"),"13",
IF(AND(B6="ST004.3",C6="ALL"),"13",
IF(AND(B6="ST004.4",C6="ALL"),"13",
IF(AND(B6="ST001",C6="ALL"),"7.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.1",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.2",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.3",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.4",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.5",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.5",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.7",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.8",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.9",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.10",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.11",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.12",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="AF016.13",C6="ALL"),"9",
IF(AND(B6="Z284.1",C6="ALL"),"9.5",
IF(AND(B6="AF001.1",C6="ALL"),"7"
)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get. Clearly I need it, lol!

Comment: If you manually typed this out, I'm so sorry.

Comment: Easier way would be to use VBA and use select case's, functions, and the general logic that VBA brings. Having a formula this long makes it impossible to ever change

Answer (score 4):

You would be much better off creating a lookup table with 3 columns:

```
1. The 100 possibilities for Cell 1.
2. The 100 answers for Cell 1 and possibility 1 of Cell 2.
3. The 100 answers for Cell 1 and possibility 2 of Cell 2.
```

Then use VLOOKUP() to lookup Cell 1 and return the answer from either Column 2 or Column 3 of the lookup table, depending on the value of Cell 2.

Here's an example with just 10 rows:

[image]

The VLOOKUP() function finds the value of Cell 1 in Column 1 of the lookup table, and returns the corresponding value from either Column 2 or Column 3, using an IF() clause that checks the value of Cell 2 to decide the column.

The formula in B6 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,D2:F11,IF(B2="Value 1",2,3),FALSE)
```

You can hide the lookup table or move it to another worksheet if necessary.

Here is more information about [VLOOKUP()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) and [IF()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function).  You should also check Excel Help.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me second Brandon Ibbotson's sentiment:  I am sorry that you had to put out the effort to come up with something that monstrous.

Now, you need to remove your business logic from your if-statement and put it somewhere maintainable instead, and then use a (relatively) simple lookup function to retrieve the correct value.  Seriously, what are you going to do if the values for ST008.6 change?

What you should do is:

On a new worksheet, set up a table.  Put your B-values down the side (in column A, starting in row 2) and your C-values across the top in row 1.  Fill in the target values at the cross-points.  Sort it by column A.

```
         US    CA    ALL
AF001.1  5.5         7
AF010   17.2
...etc...
Z284.1   8.5         9.5
```

Set up a second table that converts your top-row labels into column numbers:

```
US      2
CA      3
ALL     4
```

Note that the part numbers, or whatever they are, are column 1; we don't need a definition for that in this lookup table.

Third, define names for these two tables.  This is not strictly necessary, but it makes our formulas easier to write and the tables easier to re-use, if you need them for other formulas later.

- highlight the first table (excluding the top row)
- right-click and choose "Define Name..."
- give it a reasonable name (I'll call it XREF for this example)
- do the same for the second table (I'll call it CLKP)

Finally, on your primary sheet, replace that horrific statement with a vlookup or two:

```
=VLOOKUP(B6,XREF,VLOOKUP(C6,CLKP,2,FALSE),FALSE)
```

This is finding the value in cell B6 wherever it exists in the first column of our XREF range, and then converting the value in C6 to the column number we need, and then picking the value for that item in that column to go into the current cell.